# blockchain refresh mechanism

Tags: refresh

According to the Wolfram Warptangent, [Point Release 1 notes](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases/tag/v0.10.1), the new Monero release will `optimise the wallet blockchain refresh mechanism`

What optimizations were made and what is their impact on efficiency or performance? What new refresh functionalities were introduce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key derivation (ECDH shared secret) is now only computed once per tx, whereas before it was done per output. With a basic 2 output RingCT transaction, this should amount to approximately a 33% performance improvement (more for old-style transactions with more outputs).